# Initiate horizontal scroll based on position or div

Tags: jquery, position, horizontal-scrolling

I am trying to get a horizontal scroll to work in a single div, or rather when (top > 1400). Essentially, scroll down, meet the div in question- then scroll horizontally.
However, this either causes the elements higher up on the page to get covered by a right margin on scroll down, or disables scrolling completely.

I have been trying

```
$(function(){
   $("#art").wrapInner("<table cellspacing='30'><tr>");
   $("#info").wrap("<td></td>");
   $("#info").mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
      if (top > 1400) {
         this.scrollLeft += (delta * 30);
         event.preventDefault();
      }
      else {
         event.Default();
      }
   });   
});
```

---

```
<div id="art">
   <section id="info" data-type="background" data-speed="3" class="pages">
      ...  
   </section>
</div>
```

---

```
#info {
   background: url(time.JPG) 50% 0 repeat fixed; 
   min-height: 1000px;
   height: 730px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 300%;
   max-width: 2000px;
   position: relative;
   cursor:help;
}
```

I know this is messy I have been fumbling around trying to get this to work a couple different ways.

I got the original code from this mouse wheel example 
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/horz-scroll-with-mouse-wheel/#comment-301955